# Twig - path and dynamic methodname

Tags: twig

I want get a dynamic getter-function in twig. like this:

`{% set brick = project.software.[brickName]() %}`

But this didn't work. "brickName" is something like "getBootstrap":

`{# set brick = project.software.getBootstrap() #}`

Thanks for any idea - Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html) function, given your example and assuming the brickName is a variable set earlier, I'd use:

```
{% set brick = attribute(project.software, brickName) %}
```

In order to avoid a reference to invalid method/property, it is recommended to check before if it is defined, but maybe this would be overkill for your use case, anyway for completeness of the example, let's copy from there:

```
{{ attribute(project.software, brickName) is defined ? 'Exists!' : 'Brick method not found' }}
```

Comment: Wauhh - that's great. Thanks